# How can I loop through an object (for a simple math interpreter, in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I've been working on a simple math interpreter and I'm stuck on a problem.
I can't figure out how to loop through the object in the interpreter. My attemps either don't work at all, or cause infinite loops until Javascript reaches it's max amount of memory.

The result of the Parser would look something like this for a simple `2 + 2 + 3`:

```json
{
    "operator": "+",
    "left": {
        "operator": "+",     
        "left": {
            "type": "NUMBER",
            "value": 2       
        },
        "right": {
            "type": "NUMBER",
            "value": 2       
        }
    },
    "right": {
        "type": "NUMBER",    
        "value": 3
    }
}
```

Here's one of the attempts I've made.

```js
interpret(node) {
    node.left = this.parseNode(node.left);
    node.right = this.parseNode(node.right);

    return this.parseNum(node.left, node.right, node.operator);
}

parseNode(node) {
    let left = node.left;
    let right = node.right;

    while (left != null) {
        left = this.destructure(left);
    }
    while (right != null) {
        right = this.destructure(right);
    }

    if (left == null && right == null) {
        return { ...node };
    } else {
        return {
            type: "NUMBER",
            value: this.parseNum(left, right, node.operator),
        };
    }
}
```

The parse number (parseNum) function is pretty simple, so I don't think I need to share it. All it does is take the operator and add/multiply/subtract/divide the first two items based on that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how about you show us an attempt you've made and we can help debug.

Comment: You haven't shown your "destructuring" code. Please *do* show your attempts, we can't tell their problems otherwise.

Comment: sure, sorry about that

Comment: What do you mean by _"destructure"_? Because what you're doing doesn't appear to be the [common use of the word](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

Comment: Alright, I'll update it :/

Comment: What does `parseNum` do?

Comment: Check the edit. I stated that.

Comment: If you mean to *interpret/evaluate* the parse tree, none of the methods should be named `parse…`. This is really confusing. And `parse` should not mutate the node!

Comment: What is `parseNode` *meant* to do? Because it doesn't appear to do anything useful.

Comment: Just ignore the naming. Yes, I need help with interpreting the parse tree.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `while` loops. To me, this more looks like a depth-first recursive operation where each _node_ is reduced to a number or one of your _value_ nodes (the expected result isn't clear)

Comment: That's exactly what I need help with. I'm not sure which method I should use to complete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to recursively reduce each node into a single *value* by inspecting it and...

- If the node is already a value node, just return it
- Otherwise, create a new value node by reducing both the left and right nodes to a single value node and evaluating the result with the operator

```js
const root = {"operator":"+","left":{"operator":"+","left":{"type":"NUMBER","value":2},"right":{"type":"NUMBER","value":2}},"right":{"type":"NUMBER","value":3}}

// Operator functions
const operators = {
  "+": (l, r) => l + r,
}

// Expression evaluation
const evaluate = ({ value: l }, { value: r }, operator) =>
  operators[operator](l, r)
  
const isValueNode = node => "value" in node
  
// Reduce a node to a _value_ node
const reducer = (node) => {
  // Already a value node? Just return it
  if (isValueNode(node)) return node
  
  return {
    type: "NUMBER", // no idea what this is for ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    value: evaluate(
      reducer(node.left),  // recursively reduce the _left_ node
      reducer(node.right), // recursively reduce the _right_ node
      node.operator
    )
  }
}

console.log(reducer(root))
```